# Add data-aos inside a tag using css

Tags: css, tags, styles

I am using Drupal 7. I want to animate the login block with aos.
The login block is called "block-user-login". It´s a <div id="block-user-login" ... >
Can I create some css code around to make "data-aos='zoom-in'" be associated to that #block-user-login ?
How can I create a style script to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if you're still in doubt bout that. But you can try `<div id="block-user-login" data-aos = 'zoom-in'>` and after that you can config in css the color, the font and everything else.